# xcodebuild having .p12 with password and provisioning profile but without developer account

Tags: ios, xcode, xcodebuild, xcode7.3, code-signing-certificate

I am trying to create an .ipa build using xcodebuild.

1. I have .p12 certificate with password
2. Have provisioning profile.
3. When I pass these two data with xcodebuild with login in xcode preferences, build get created
4. Where as, when I pass these two data with xcodebuild without login in xcode preferences, build get failed with error **"SecKey API returned: -25308, [Code path]: unknown error -1=ffffffffffffffff"**

Here are script main build code:

> xcodebuild -workspace "TestApp.xcworkspace" -scheme "TestAppScheme"
>   -derivedDataPath "${PROJECT_BUILDDIR}" CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="${developerName}"
>   OTHER_CODE_SIGN_FLAGS="--keychain ${KEYCHAIN_NAME}" -configuration
>   Release clean build /usr/bin/xcrun -sdk iphoneos
>   PackageApplicationFixed -v
>   "${PROJECT_BUILDDIR}/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/${PROJECT_NAME}.app"
>   -o "${BUILD_HISTORY_DIR}/${APPLICATION_NAME}_${BUILD_ID}.ipa" --sign "${developerName}" --embed "${PROVISONNING_PROFILE}" }

```
PackageApplicationFixed diff with original one:
diff PackageApplication PackageApplicationFixed                                                                                                                                                                                    [12:08]
155,158c155,156
<     my @codesign_args = ("/usr/bin/codesign", "--force", "--preserve-metadata=identifier,entitlements,resource-rules",
<                          "--sign", $opt{sign},
<                          "--resource-rules=$destApp/ResourceRules.plist");
< 
---
>     my @codesign_args = ("/usr/bin/codesign", "--force", "--preserve-metadata=identifier,entitlements",
>                          "--sign", $opt{sign});
```

Xcode Version : 7.3
mac version : 10.12

I tried both developer and production certificate, but no help.
I appreciate any help on this.

Comment: Allowing all applications to access this item" in Keychain Access for to the private key of certificate.

Comment: @NarendraPandey, yes I provide all access.

Comment: Unlock your keychain by adding this line to your projects configuration (Build>Execute shell)